# How to get technical details from a QR code?

Tags: qr-code, reverse-engineering

I have developed a QR code generation code for a client; however, they expect another QR code (visually) than what my code generates.
Although, I respected all the configuration of QR generation, but that seems to be issue there.

Hence, is it possible to reverse engineer the configurations from a QR code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This project is a nice tool and provides a lot of details of a QR code:

https://merricx.github.io/qrazybox/